# SQL query to find highest GPA

Tags: sql

I am currently taking a Stanford online MOOC course on SQL. I have a question in regards to an SQL query. I have three tables: `Student`, `Apply`, and `College`. Student has student ID (`sID`) and GPA (`GPA`). Apply has the college name (`cName`) and Student ID. College has the college name (`cName`) and state the college is in (`state`). This is the query the teacher is using:

```
Select distinct College.cName, state, GPA
From College, Apply, Student
Where College.cName = Apply.cName
And Apply.sID = Student.sID
And GPA >= all (select GPA from Student, Apply
Where Student.sID = Apply.sID
And Apply.cName = College.cName)
```

I don't understand why we need `Student.sID=Apply.sID and Apply.cName=College.cName`. I know it makes sure they match up, but why is this necessary?

Comment: Also, what we are trying to do is find colleges and pair those colleges with the highest GPA among their applicants. If someone can dumb down for me how this is doing that it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. If you need to add info to your question, edit your question.

Comment: 2. Read up on SQL JOINs.

Comment: Not sure why the teacher is using the old way of JOINS

Answer (score 1):

Your professor is using old style joins which are hard to undestand here is it written in new style joins

```
Select distinct College.cName, state, GPA
From Student
JOIN College on College.cName = Apply.cName
JOIN Apply on Apply.sID = Student.sID
WHERE GPA >= all (
  select GPA 
  from Student
  JOIN Apply ON Student.sID = Apply.sID AND Apply.cName = College.cName
)
```

Old style joins were old in the 90s.  Your teacher is living in the past.

Of course this example is horrible for teaching anything in general but even worse if students don't even understand simple joins yet.

I'm sorry.

> side note -- if your question is does the order matter in `Student.sID = Apply.sID AND Apply.cName = College.cName` -- The answer is no.  In a compare like this it is the same as `Apply.sID = Student.sID AND College.cName = Apply.cName`

Comment: The fact they are using an inline query that joins that way just makes it that much better

Comment: @CupofJava -- I would use `MAX` on a `GROUP BY` before using `ALL` here.  `ALL` is also very old school.

Comment: I've never seen it written like this. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is to find all matching rows in the Apply table that student has applied to a college and find all the college names that student has applied to from college table. Also let me correct you Student, Apply and College are not databases here. They are tables of your database. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me! I would have sounded really dumb on my interview lol

Answer (score 0):

The line: From College, Apply, Student
is an implicit join. The were Student.sID=Appply.sID and Apply.cName=College.cName lines are to tell the query how to match the tables together.

If no restrictions are given, it will take each item on the table College, duplicate it for the number of rows in Apply and have amend each row of apply to every row of College (cross multiply). Then duplicate the newly created table 'College joined to Apply' for each item on the table Student and apply each item on the table Student to each of the duplicated rows.

Comment: duplicate is the wrong word here -- maybe "return a row for each" or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What would be wrong with these duplications? Is it computing time?

Comment: @Smw10c - using the word "duplication" is wrong because it conceptually wrong -- they aren't duplications -- they are multiple rows that have the same content.  It is a subtle point but one that will be clearer if you use SQL for a long time.